# Setting a reminder date based on product selected

Tags: android

I set up a Date_Picker that allows the user to select which date and time to set a reminder but I need to have it set up where they choose which medication they are ordering and it will set a reorder reminder to x amount of days in the future.  If they order Medication "A" then they will get a reminder in 5 days. If they order Medication "B" reminder in 10 days. Medication "C" 15 days.   I am assuming I need to remove the references to the Date_Picker?  and have my code mCalendar.set(Calendar.Year, year) use year as a string somehow?  I'm pretty lost right now!   Here is the code I have. Thank you.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mDbHelper = new RemindersDbAdapter(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.reminder_edit);

    mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);
    mDateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reminder_date);
    mTimeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reminder_time);

    mConfirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);

    mRowId = savedInstanceState != null ?savedInstanceState.getLongRemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) 
                                        : null;

    registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText();
}

private void setRowIdFromIntent() {
    if (mRowId == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();            
        mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) 
                                : null;

    }
}


@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch(id) {
        case DATE_PICKER_DIALOG: 
            return showDatePicker();
        case TIME_PICKER_DIALOG: 
            return showTimePicker(); 
    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}

private DatePickerDialog showDatePicker() {


    DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog
(ReminderEditActivity.this,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateDateButtonText(); 
        }
   }, mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),mCalendar.getCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); 
    return datePicker; 
}


private void registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText() {

    mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_PICKER_DIALOG);  
        }
    }); 



    mConfirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            saveState(); 
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            Toast.makeText(ReminderEditActivity.this, getString(R.string.task_saved_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish(); 
        }

    });

      updateDateButtonText(); 
      updateTimeButtonText();
}

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, and please remove the code which is unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the Date and Time pickers and instead use a Spinner for choosing a medication.

Use getSelectedItem() of the spinner to get the selected medication. Based on the selected medication find out the reminder interval. Finally, add the interval to the current date using Calendar.add() and get the reminder date.